# Erro ao usar condicional If

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estou tentando analisar os dados da seguinte tabela. Isso é uma registro de trades só para deixar claro.

DATAFRAME:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
def lista_preco():
    
    
    #ainda falta resolver os trades depois de 19h
    
    lista_dias = df['DATE'].unique().tolist()
    lista = df['pair'].unique().tolist()
    lista_buy = []
    lista_sell = []
    
    
    for dias in lista_dias:
        for tickers in lista:
            if (df['pair']== tickers and df['type'] == 'sell'):

                mask1 = (df['pair']== tickers and df['type'] == 'sell')

                df2 = df[mask1]
                df2['price_vol'] = df2['price'] * df2['vol']
                preco = df2['price_vol'].sum(axis = 0) / df2['vol'].sum(axis = 0)
                lista_sell.append([dias,tickers,preco,"LONG"])

            if (df['pair']== tickers and df['type'] == 'buy'):

                mask2 = df['pair']== tickers and df['type'] == 'buy'

                df2 = df[mask2]
                df2['price_vol'] = df2['price'] * df2['vol']
                preco = df2['price_vol'].sum(axis = 0) / df2['vol'].sum(axis = 0)
                lista_buy.append([dias, tickers, preco, "SHORT"])

    return lista_buy, lista_sell
```

ERRO:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-d301c71c9e88> in <module>
----> 1 lista_preco()

<ipython-input-15-8ac3ff545e1d> in lista_preco()
     12     for dias in lista_dias:
     13         for tickers in lista:
---> 14             if (df['pair']== tickers and df['type'] == 'sell'):
     15 
     16                 mask1 = (df['pair']== tickers and df['type'] == 'sell')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1477     def __nonzero__(self):
   1478         raise ValueError(
-> 1479             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1480             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1481         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Ajudaria se facultasses o CSV ou uma amostra dele para conseguir testar, e dissesses o que pretendes como resultado final

Comment: O que eu quero fazer com esses dados é calcular o preço médio(já sei como faz).

Mas a questão é que eu preciso calcular o preço médio para operações de compra("buy" = "LONG") e venda("sell" = "SHORT") de forma separaDA para um mesmo ativo. Além disso, também preciso registrar a data em que a operação aconteceu e o volume("vol") em uma lista de lista. tipo : [[DATA,PAIR,PREÇO,"LONG"], ...]

Comment: Podes facultar o csv pf, apenas algumas linhas servem

Comment: O csv é no seguinte formato:

DATE;time;pair;type;ordertype;price;cost;fee;vol;margin;misc
30/12/2020;15:11:05;ABEV3;buy;market;10;1000;12;300;0;0
30/12/2020;15:10:08;MRV3;buy;limit;20;15500;9;200;0;0
30/12/2020;15:09:11;PETR4;sell;limit;30;4516;8;100;0;0
30/12/2020;13:46:53;ABEV3;buy;market;40;45415;10;500;0;0
30/12/2020;13:20:07;TAEE11;buy;limit;10;5465;13;600;0;0

Comment: É o precço médio por dia para cada um dos tipos? Ou o preço médio total para cada um dos tipos?

Comment: Preço médio por dia para cada um dos ativos com distinção entre buy e sell. Aqui está como se calcula o preço médio: https://ajuda.easynvest.com.br/hc/pt-br/articles/360049317813-Como-realizar-o-c%C3%A1lculo-do-Pre%C3%A7o-M%C3%A9dio-

Comment: Confere pf se a resposta resolve o problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que estás a complicar mais do que realmente é necessário.

Tendo:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv = StringIO("""DATE;time;pair;type;ordertype;price;cost;fee;vol;margin;misc
30/12/2020;15:11:05;ABEV3;buy;market;10;1000;12;300;0;0
30/12/2020;15:11:05;ABEV3;sell;market;15;1000;12;300;0;0
30/12/2020;15:10:08;MRV3;buy;limit;20;15500;9;200;0;0
31/12/2020;15:09:11;PETR4;sell;limit;30;4516;8;100;0;0
30/12/2020;13:46:53;ABEV3;buy;market;40;45415;10;500;0;0
31/12/2020;13:20:07;TAEE11;buy;limit;10;5465;13;600;0;0
31/12/2020;13:20:07;TAEE11;sell;limit;10;5465;13;600;0;0
""")

df = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=";")
```

Acresentar a coluna total_price:

```
df['total_price'] = df['price'] * df['vol']
```

df:

```
         DATE      time    pair  type ordertype  price   cost  fee  vol  margin  misc  total_price
0  30/12/2020  15:11:05   ABEV3   buy    market     10   1000   12  300       0     0         3000
1  30/12/2020  15:11:05   ABEV3  sell    market     15   1000   12  300       0     0         4500
2  30/12/2020  15:10:08    MRV3   buy     limit     20  15500    9  200       0     0         4000
3  31/12/2020  15:09:11   PETR4  sell     limit     30   4516    8  100       0     0         3000
4  30/12/2020  13:46:53   ABEV3   buy    market     40  45415   10  500       0     0        20000
5  31/12/2020  13:20:07  TAEE11   buy     limit     10   5465   13  600       0     0         6000
6  31/12/2020  13:20:07  TAEE11  sell     limit     10   5465   13  600       0     0         6000
```

Podemos começar por agrupar e calcular o preço médio por ativo por type e dia, presumindo que 'activo' é o pair, e fazer um `sum()` do `total_price` e `vol` e calcular a média.

```
df_tmp = df.groupby(['pair','type', 'DATE'], as_index=False).agg({'total_price': 'sum', 'vol': 'sum'})
df_tmp['mean_price'] = df_tmp['total_price'] / df_tmp['vol']
df_tmp.drop(['vol', 'total_price'], axis=1, inplace=True) # drop das colunas visto que ja nao precisamos
```

df_tmp:

```
     pair  type        DATE  mean_price
0   ABEV3   buy  30/12/2020       28.75
1   ABEV3  sell  30/12/2020       15.00
2    MRV3   buy  30/12/2020       20.00
3   PETR4  sell  31/12/2020       30.00
4  TAEE11   buy  31/12/2020       10.00
5  TAEE11  sell  31/12/2020       10.00
```

Quanto ao segundo tema comentado podemos mudar os valores da coluna type, já que não os vamos usar para neste problema, com "SHORT" ou "LONG" consoante a condição pedida:

```
df_tmp['type'] = df_tmp['type'].apply(lambda t: "SHORT" if t == 'sell' else 'LONG')
```

df_tmp:

```
     pair   type        DATE  mean_price
0   ABEV3   LONG  30/12/2020       28.75
1   ABEV3  SHORT  30/12/2020       15.00
2    MRV3   LONG  30/12/2020       20.00
3   PETR4  SHORT  31/12/2020       30.00
4  TAEE11   LONG  31/12/2020       10.00
5  TAEE11  SHORT  31/12/2020       10.00
```

E por fim, convertê-las para a lista de listas pedida:

```
lista = df_tmp.values.tolist()
```

lista:

```
[['ABEV3', 'LONG', '30/12/2020', 28.75], ['ABEV3', 'SHORT', '30/12/2020', 15.0], ['MRV3', 'LONG', '30/12/2020', 20.0], ['PETR4', 'SHORT', '31/12/2020', 30.0], ['TAEE11', 'LONG', '31/12/2020', 10.0], ['TAEE11', 'SHORT', '31/12/2020', 10.0]]
```

Comment: Oi miguel, o preço médio nesse caso serie o "mean_price"/volume transacionado. É um preço médio ponderado pelo volume.

Comment: O que queres dizer? Por ex, para a primeira linha `ABEV3` em que o `mean_price` é 11500, será 11500/300? Podes explicar esse calculo com um exemplo do df original pf

Comment: exatamente isso!

Comment: Pedro, editei a resposta, confere pf se é o pretendido

Comment: acho que vc está somando algo a mais. O resultado correto para o ABEV3 seria 28,75.

linha 1 + linha 2 =  (10 x 300) + (40 x 500) =  23000/(300+500)  =  28,75

Comment: Pedro, resposta editada, confere pf